# RxJava 2 "Hello World" not printing anything

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm completely new to RxJava (and reactive programming in general). Thus, I decided to write a simple program to grasp some basic concepts. It's a pretty basic program which is supposed to print an String value. Unfortunately, it doesn't print anything at all, even some error I could catch. I tried to debug it but it seems the whole thing has been unable to even start.

Which could be wrong? Any help would be appreciated. That's the code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    checkForNewString();
}

public static Completable checkForNewString() {
    return Completable.create(emitter -> {
        captureString()
        .doOnSuccess(s -> System.out.println(s))
        .doOnError(throwable -> emitter.onError(new RuntimeException("Error")))
        .subscribe();
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
}

public static Single<String> captureString() {
   return Single.create(emitter -> {
       String test = generateString();
       emitter.onSuccess(test);
   });
}

public static String generateString() {
    return "Test";
}
```

}

Comment: Please read the [Getting Started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#getting-started).

Comment: @akarnokd If possible, I don't want to use _just_

Comment: You are throwing away the `Completable` returned by `checkForNewString()`.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd and congratulations for this amazing tool

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I didn't need that Observable. Here's the code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkForNewString();
}


public static void checkForNewString() {
    captureString()
       .doOnSuccess(s -> System.out.println(s))
       .subscribe();
}

public static Single<String> captureString() {
   return Single.create(emitter -> {
       String test = generateString();
       emitter.onSuccess(test);
   });
}

public static String generateString() {
    return "Test";
}
```

}